# SELECT COMMAND SQL more than 1 value

Tags: sql

Im trying to create a select command to query the database I have and find different values from different tables in the database.

Comment: And what are all the columns on those tables?

Comment: This is what I have tried:

SELECT Movie.title, Movie.year, Actor.firstName, Actor.lastName, Role.roleName From Movie, Actor, Role WHERE quoteID='Houston, we have a problem.';
/

Comment: Which table are quotes stored in?  The answer from @Dor Cohen looks like the right approach but you haven't said where to find a quote for a movie

Comment: the quote from the movie comes from the Quote table and is listed as quoteCHAR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, I change all ID columns from CHAR to NUMBER

```
CREATE TABLE Actor
(actorID NUMBER,
lastName CHAR(24),
firstName CHAR(24),
middleName CHAR(24),
suffix CHAR(6),
gender CHAR(1),
birthDate DATE,
deathDate DATE)
/

CREATE TABLE Movie
(movieID NUMBER,
title CHAR(36),
year NUMBER,
company CHAR(50),
totalNoms NUMBER,
awardsWon NUMBER,
DVDPrice NUMBER(5,2),
discountPrice NUMBER(5,2))
/

CREATE TABLE Role
(roleID NUMER,
roleName CHAR(36),
gender CHAR(1),
actorID NUMBER,
movieID NUMBER)
/

CREATE TABLE Quote
(quoteID NUMBER,
quoteCHAR CHAR(255))
/

CREATE TABLE RoleQuote
(roleID NUMBER,
quoteID NUMBER)
/
```

and the select will be:

```
SELECT  Movie.Title , Movie.Year , Actor.Firstname, Actor.lastname, Role.roleName, Quote.quoteCHAR 
FROM    Movie, Actor, Role, Quote, RoleQuote
WHERE   Movie.movieID = Role.movieId AND 
    Actor.actorID = Role.ActorId AND 
    Role.roleID = RoleQuote.roleID AND
    Quote.quoteID = RoleQuote.quoteID AND
    Quote.quoteCHAR LIKE '%Houston, we have a problem.%'
```

Comment: I'd hope schools are teaching INNER JOIN syntax by now. It's 2012, after all.

Comment: This is what I have been working on no idea if its close but from what I am aware I am sure it is not necessary to add the two tables you are suggesting:

SELECT Movie.title, Movie.year, Actor.firstName, Actor.lastName, Role.roleName FROM Movie, Actor, Role WHERE Quote.quoteCHAR ='Houston, we have a problem.';
/

Comment: How you connect between movie and Actor? is there only one movie per actor?

Comment: SELECT Movie.title, Movie.year, Actor.firstName, Actor.lastName, Quote.quoteCHAR, Role.roleName FROM Movie, Actor, Quote, Role WHERE Quote.quoteCHAR ='Houston, we have a problem.';
/

when I use the above it makes it go crazy and doesnt stop listing things

Comment: It's because you have Cartesian product you have to perform JOIN on this table by related columnms

Comment: ive added above all the create tables at the start to show the conection

Comment: @user1300580 It works? if so +1 my answer and accept it (press on the green mark below answer rank, 3 after you will +1)